# How do I only print a statement when the end of file is reached in Bison?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

For simplification of the original problem, supposed I wanted to parse a string of left and right parentheses. The flex file would have the tokens

```
"(" return LPAREN
")" return RPAREN
```

and the bison file would have the productions

```
completedparse: pair {printf("Success!\n");}
;
pair: LPAREN pair RPAREN
    | LPAREN RPAREN pair
    | LPAREN RPAREN
;
```

IF given the string "(()()(()))" or "()()(())" It would succeed.

The problem I have is that "(()()))" would print the success statement, immediately before failure. I know that bison creates the production

```
$accept: completedparse $end
```

which is how bison accepts or rejects the string. All my problems would go away if I could write my own $accept production and include any print statements in that production. But according to the 3.0.2 manual $accept cannot be used in the grammar.

My problems would also go away if I could modify the return value of yyparse() (assume that I need more information than just 0 => success, 1 => failure). I don't think this is possible though.

If you have any insight please respond, and thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution:

```
completedparse: pair {printf("Success!\n");} 
              | pair error
              ;
```

The `error` pseudo-terminal won't match all errors, but it will match the one where an EOF is expected and something else is found. If the error is encountered in some other context, the error production won't apply. In general, you should use `yyerror` to perform an action on a syntax error; the above rule is simply a way to avoid invoking the `completedparse` action in the case that there is garbage at the end of the input.

By the way, your grammar does not match `(())()`. You might want to use:

```
pair:         /* EMPTY */
    |         '(' pair ')' pair
    ;
```

**Additionally:**

In response to the addendum in the comments:

1. You can use the action `{ YYABORT }` in the error production in order to immediately return (with a return value of 1, indicating a syntax error). If you want to print a generic error message, you are probably better off doing so in your `yyerror` implementation, since that will be called on any syntax error, while the `error` production will only be reduced on certain errors. You can use `error` productions to generate more specific error messages, but that's a lot more work.
2. You cannot customize the `$accept` pseudo-production. However, the above technique is more or less equivalent.
3. You cannot change the return type or values of `yyparse` (0 success, 1 syntax error, 2 allocation error). However, it is often useful to return more data from a parse (for example, an AST). The "traditional" solution is to just use a global variable, but for those of us with a distaste for global variables, another solution is to use the `[%parse-param][1]` declaration to add one or more additional arguments; normally, your start production will set the value of the objects to which these arguments point. If you do this, you should always check the return value of `yyparse` before relying on the additional return information, exactly because the start production may be evaluated even in the case of an error.

Comment: This grammar isn't close to the actual assignment, the real grammar I created is correct apart from the error problem.

Comment: @CullenS: Yeah, I figured, but in case someone else finds this question I thought it was worth fixing.

Comment: This grammar isn't close to the actual assignment, the real grammar I created is correct apart from the error problem. I know of the error token, but if I include that, won't the value returned from yyparse be 0 indicating success not 1? But that wouldn't be a problem if I put an print-error statement after the "pair error" production. Just to be clear, it is impossible to do the custom $accept production and/or change return value of yyparse?        Thanks for the help by the way, huge help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, very insightful.